# Is there a way in Tesseract to capture text meta-data along with text?

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to figure out if text metadata like font-size, font-family, bold/italic etc. can be captured using Tesseract. Below is the code I used to try it but that did not work and returned **"None"**. Using, **Tesseract version = 4.1.1, Tesseract-OCR engine version = 5.0.0**

```
with open(Image_file_location, "rb") as image:
f = image.read()
b = bytearray(f)

with tesserocr.PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(b))
    api.SetImage(image)
    api.Recognize()
    iterator = api.GetIterator()
    print(iterator.WordFontAttributes())
```

Currently, using Tesseract, I was able to capture text properly but not meta-data. I have attached a sample image file and example expected output.

[image]

**Expected Output:**
[Font:"some_font", Font_family:"some_font_family", Bold, font_size:"some_font_size] GCEO Review

[Font:"some_font", Font_family:"some_font_family", Bold, font_size:"some_font_size] Dear Shareholders,

[Font:"some_font", Font_family:"some_font_family", Bold, font_size:"some_font_size] TURNING THE....

[Font:"some_font", Font_family:"some_font_family", Bold, font_size:"some_font_size] We have executed well and gained mobile share in our core.........

So, basically, wherever there is a change in meta-data, we should be able to capture the information and prepend that information before that sentence.

Comment: No answer/suggestions from any fellow member... Does this mean, it's not possible??

Comment: I'm about to ask a similar question (although with emphasis on bolding), but I fear the answer is "no", at least not in Tesseract.  Stand by...

Comment: ok, my post is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67577793/.

Comment: I am wondering the same.